# Python convert datetime to another format

Tags: python, datetime, date-conversion

I want to convert a column in my python dataframe. The column is of type object.

From
Dec-21-20 09:20PM

to This
2020-12-21 21:20:00:00.000

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['your_column_name'])`

Answer (score 0):

`df["column"] = pd.to_datetime(df["column"])`

If you need more specific formatting, edit your question and comment back so I can adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: looks great any way I can convert it with out the darn T in the middle? 2020-04-23T19:49:00

Comment: I think so, comment back what the result is, and then let me compare to the documentation. I'll stand by.

Comment: Interesting the T only appears when I view dataframe what I print it on to screen its not there.

Comment: Ah ok, that's something with console formatting. Did you need help with console formatting or are you ok with how it prints?

Comment: I am fine with how it prints I am new to python. I will be exporting to a sql table will it go with that T as well? I rather not have that T there it will cause issues in SQL if it is expecting a datetime. The T will create type error. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It shouldn't, but it will all depend on your parameters. Try [df.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) and see what prints in the console.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to convert it into `dtype: datetime64[ns]`

then use: `df["column"] = pd.to_datetime(df["column"])`

or specify your format

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['05/23/2005']), format="%m/%d/%Y")
Out[12]:
0   2005-05-23
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

once you have that you can use `pandas.Series.dt.strftime` to any format of string you want

Comment: Got it thank you! You been more that helpful!